# Can we enhance the extension by zero-pullback adjunction to hom sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

$
\def\Mod{\operatorname{Mod}}
\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\Homs{\mathcal{H}om}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}
\def\F{\mathcal{F}}
\def\G{\mathcal{G}}
$
Let $X$ be a ringed space, $U\subset X$ be an open subset and $j:U\to X$ be the inclusion. Then the functor $j^{-1}:\Mod(\O_X)\to\Mod(\O_U)$ has a left adjoint, $j_!:\Mod(\O_U)\to\Mod(\O_X)$, the extension by zero (for details, see [009Z](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/009Z) for example).

Given a morphism of ringed spaces $f:X\to Y$, the adjunction $f^*:\Mod(\O_Y)\rightleftarrows\Mod(\O_X):f_*$ can be enhanced to a hom sheaf isomorphism
$$
f_*\mathcal{H}om_{\O_X}(f^*\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \cong \mathcal{H}om_{\O_Y}(\mathcal{F},f_*\mathcal{G}).
$$
(See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1114387/394668), for example).

I was wondering if something similar could be performed with the adjunction $j_!\dashv j^{-1}$. Maybe something like this?
$$
\tag{1}\label{sheaf_adj}
\Homs_{\O_X}(j_!\F,\G)\cong j_*\Homs_{\O_U}(\F,j^{-1}\G).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\Mod{\operatorname{Mod}}
\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\Homs{\mathcal{H}om}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}
\def\F{\mathcal{F}}
\def\G{\mathcal{G}}
$
The answer is yes: the relation $(1)$ is true. By Corollary 3 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489849/394668), we have
$$
\Homs_{\O_X}(j_!\F,\G)\cong\Homs_{\O_X}(j_{p!}\F,\G),
$$
where $j_{p!}\F$ denotes the extension by zero presheaf. We shall prove the latter is isomorphic to $j_*\Homs_{\O_U}(\F,\underbrace{j^{-1}\G}_{\G|_U})$. We are going to change notation: instead of $j$ we will write $j^X_U$, and instead of $j_{p!}$ we will write $j_{U,p!}^X$. For an open set $V\subset X$, we have
\begin{align}
\Homs_{\O_X}(j_{U,p!}^X\F,\G)(V)
&=\Hom_{\O_V}(j_{U,p!}^X\F|_{V},\G|_{V})\\
&=\Hom_{\O_V}(j_{U\cap V,p!}^V(\F|_{U\cap V}),\G|_V)\\
&\cong\Hom_{\O_{U\cap V}}(\F|_{U\cap V},\G|_{U\cap V})\\
&=\Homs_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\F,\G|_U)(U\cap V)\\
&=j_{U*}^X\Homs_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\F,\G|_U)(V).
\end{align}
So we have bijections on sections. Why do they commute with restrictions? This is due to the way the adjunction $j_!\dashv j^{-1}$ works. See [00A3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00A3), for example.